# Correct way of updating checkbox with keyboard press in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, checkbox

I've got the following code:

```
export default function Tag(props: { tag: ITag, setTag: (tag: string) => void }) {
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false)

    const handleTagChange = () => {
        props.setTag(props.tag.abbreviation);
        var element = document.getElementById(props.tag.abbreviation);
        if (!checked) {
            element?.classList.add("label-toggle")
        }
        else {
            element?.classList.remove("label-toggle")
        }
        setChecked(!checked)
    }

    return (
        <div id={props.tag.abbreviation} className='label-button' onClick={handleTagChange}>
            <input id='check' key={props.tag.hotkey} checked={checked} onChange={handleTagChange} type="checkbox" />
            <div className='label-title'>{props.tag.abbreviation}</div>
            <div className='label-icon' style={{ backgroundColor: props.tag.colour }}></div>
            <div className='label-hotkey'>{props.tag.hotkey}</div>
        </div>
        
    )
```

Everything works as expected if I use mouse click to trigger the checkbox. It works both if I press on the checkbox or the surrounding div with function `handleTagChange()`

I've added a key listener, so that the checkbox can be triggered with a keyboard key press.

```
const handleHotKey = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
    if (e.key == props.tag.hotkey) {
        handleTagChange();
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', e => { handleHotKey(e) }, false)
}, [])
```

Key listener works, key press is detected, however the value of the checked state simply does not update.

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. What is the correct way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, it's common practice to wrap an `input` element inside a `label`, which are programmatically associated with each other.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

The standard way of handling events is to use the `event`, which is passed into the `onChange` callback. When a checkbox is changed, you can access its checked state through the `event.target.checked` attribute.

I've also noticed a common mistake of directly manipulating DOM elements. React was created to solve this particular problem. In your example, there's no need to work with elements in this way.

```
type Props =  {
    tag: ITag,
    setTag: (tag: string) => void
}

export default function Tag({ tag, setTag }: Props) {
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false)

    const handleTagChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setChecked(event.target.checked);
        setTag(tag.abbreviation);
    }

    // React will guarantee a consistency
    const className = `label-button ${checked ? '' : 'label-toggle'}`

    return (
        <label className={className} onClick={handleTagChange}>
            <input checked={checked} onChange={handleTagChange} type="checkbox" />
            <div className='label-title'>{tag.abbreviation}</div>
            <div className='label-icon' style={{ backgroundColor: tag.colour }}></div>
            <div className='label-hotkey'>{tag.hotkey}</div>
        </label>
        
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Implementing your solution gives an error as onClick expects  MouseEvent and handleTagChange uses ChangeEvent. How can I fix this?

Comment: Yes, i think you can remove the onClick handler `<label className={className}>`